# Finding all mixed Nash equilibria in a $3\times 3$ game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I was looking at the exercise $2$ in this file http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1531493.files/Practice%20Problem%20Solutions%20on%20Nash%20Equilibrium.pdf pages 4 to 7.
I do not understand why at the exercise concludes without checking for all possible supports for player 2, as done for player 1.
Is it correct to consider only all possible supports of just one of the two players? If so, why? Also, it would be indifferent which of the two player is choosen?
If it is not in general enough to consider all the supports for just one of the two players, what makes it correct in that case? What do it in general?

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to this specific problem or type of problem. Case analysis always works by covering a complete set of mutually exclusive cases, i.e. cases whose union includes all possibilities. Player $1$ must have some support; if you've covered all possible supports for player $1$, you've covered all possible cases. There's nothing deep or game-theoretic about that.

Comment: How it would be covered , for example, the case in which 1's support contains all 3 actions, while 2's support only two? We have considered such a support of 1 only with respect to the "full" support of 2, so why it covers also the other cases for the "full" support of 1? Similar reasoning for other supports of 1.

Comment: @user98139: This is a different question from what you orginally asked. You're now saying not that it's not enough to cover all cases for the support of player $1$, but that one of these cases hasn't been fully covered, since only the subcase of full support for player $2$ was covered. That's not in fact the case; the text makes no assumption about player $2$'s support.

Comment: So, actually the linked exercise is not complete, right? In order to make a complete solution it should be done a specular reasoning to that made for player 1, but with respect to player 2 (to be more precise, player 2's support). Is that correct?

Comment: @user98139: No, you're still misunderstanding. The exercise is complete and perfectly right as it is. I countered both your objections to it. First (in the question) you objected to it not covering cases for player $2$. I replied that this objection is not valid, since all cases for player $1$ are covered and that's a complete set of cases, independent of the support of player $2$. Then you raised a second objection (in the comment) that the exercise doesn't in fact cover all cases for player $1$ because it makes unwarranted assumptions about the support for player $2$ in one of those cases.

Comment: @user98139: I replied that this objection is also not valid because no such assumptions are made. The exercise fully covers each case of the support of player $1$, without making any assumptions about the support of player $2$; hence it covers all cases and finds all equilibria.

Comment: It seems that I cannot explain myself properly, sorry. I try to ask it in a different way: whether the exercise asks to find all the equilibria in this game for both players, I must consider also all possible supports of 2. Is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37280/discussion-between-joriki-and-user98139).